# How can I acces the checkbox state frrom a setup dialog

Tags: c#, installation

I'm new with the installer package.
I'm trying to creat an action that will take in consideration the check box state on th setup dialog.
How can i acces this values? I have no idea how to retrieve informaton from the user dialogs.
Thanks

Comment: What installer are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to acess value of the property that is attached to that checkbox using the [session.property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/session-session).

The unselected state sets the property to null.For details, please check the [CheckBox Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/checkbox-control) article.

Assuming you're using one of the standard installer authoring tools and that you will process the property from a custom action, here is an article that shows how to [get/set a property value](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/set-windows-installer-property-custom-action.html) withing different type of custom actions.

Except for the PowerShell example, all the samples from the above example work in an MSI package, no matter what authoring tool you used to build it.